# ReportViewer (SSRS) with VB.NET Appearance error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reportviewer

I want to embed a .net webpage with ReportViewer object.
I created a test project and have:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" >
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" bordercolor="Navy" borderstyle="Solid" borderwidth="1px" height="100%" tooltip="Display Report" width="100%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote">
                    <ServerReport ReportPath="/sales" ReportServerUrl="http://server/reportserver" />
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

However, the buttons of the report are huge. 
See images:

[image]
[image]

Any reason for that? Thanks

Comment: I guess no one can figure out what is my issue here?

Comment: Which browser? All of them? Any proxies or gateways? Is there any chance that something in your CSS is causing a render conflict?  Is it just on your machine or others too?

Comment: All browsers. I'm just using a new and plain website project in VS2012

Comment: If you use developer toolbar/firebug/etc in your browser of choice, does it list any errors in the network panel? Have you inspected the HTML in the browser for any odd image sizing/zooming? Is the browser zoomed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it. It was a CSS format issue:

```
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Removed it and everything is fine now.
Thanks everyone.