# ReportViewer deformed toolbar

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I used the ReportViewer in VS2012 on an asp.net page and the toolbar is not rendering well (see image)[image: thats how the toolbar for reportviewer appears in design mode] [image: and on the production machine it appers like this.]. Please assist!!

Comment: This is happening in IE 9 and 10, with the ReportViewewr that comes with VS2012

Comment: I have the same issue, buttons are really big in the report for some reason. No one was able to respond to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515418/reportviewer-ssrs-with-vb-net-appearance-error

Comment: seems this has something to do with the css styles defined in the vs2012 asp.net web application template. I removed the reference to the css file and my report toolbar rendered correctly. Now I can't figure out which element in the css is causing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got the solution. As I suspected, it's the css. If you check the defaults Site.css that VS2012 creates, it sets input and textarea propoerties which affect the reportviewer tool bar. The lines below are the culprit 
**`input, textarea { border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; background: #fff; color: #333; font-size: 1.2em; margin: 5px 0 6px 0; padding: 5px; width: 300px; }`** this sets the width of the textarea/input to 300px which affects these controls in reportviewer toolbar. You may also need to edit or comment out the styles under /*tables*/

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps to fix this issue but dot forget to take backup from the file because this is will effect the site style if you use Microsoft style.

1- locate the css file and open it which in the project folder\content\site.css.
2-find the following text (input, textarea) and remove the setting between {}
from

```
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

to

```
input, textarea {
}
```

3- change the td which under table which is like this
From

```
td {
padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
border: 0 none;
```

}

To

```
td {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border: 0 none;
```

}

Now, your life it seems good.