# SSRS parameter dropdown looking very big with reportviewer

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, display, report-viewer2012

ZUsing Reportviewer with Visual studio 2013 and SSRS 2008 I am facing issue where multi value parameter, calendar and show/hide parameter dropdown looking awfully big. I don't have access to Report server , so can't change css or any setting there.Here is a screenshot for the same. Not sure how to resolve this now.

#### Show/Hide Parameter drop down looking aweful

[image: Show/Hide Parameter drop down looking aweful]

#### Calendar Parameter icon looking very big and similar is the case with multi value parameters

[image: Calendar Parameter icon looking very big and similar is the case with multi value parameters]

Comment: here is a related thread which I am not able to understand on what exactly  has to be removed.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515418/reportviewer-ssrs-with-vb-net-appearance-error/35130533#35130533

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another post by Mike, Thanks Mike.
[ReportViewer (SSRS) with VB.NET Appearance error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515418/reportviewer-ssrs-with-vb-net-appearance-error/35130533#35130533)

Basically, you need to remove the section Mike has mentioned in his post from Site.css file which is default stylesheet file with your web project and you are done.